# Chart.js number Y-AXIS label format for many decimal places

Tags: javascript, chart.js, label

I'm having problems with chart.js Y-axis labels. I have the following data.

```
var data = {
labels: ["1","2","3","4","5"],
datasets: [
    {
        label: "My First dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
        highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
        highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: [0.15000000000000088,0.15000000000000133,0.15000000000000177,0.15000000000000221,0.15000000000000308]
    },
]
};
```

and I get this result.

[Image of the Graph Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9g0W4.png)

As you can see the labels in the Y-axis are cut after the fifth decimal place.  How do I show all the decimal places from my data in the Y-Axis labels?

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var data = {
labels: ["1","2","3","4","5"],
datasets: [
    {
        label: "My First dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
        highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
        highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: [15000000000000088,15000000000000133,15000000000000177,15000000000000221,15000000000000308]
    },
]
};

// create chart
var ctx = document.getElementById("radaranalytics").getContext('2d');
var radar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(data, {
  scaleBeginAtZero: false,
  scaleLabel: "<%=value/100000000000000000%>",
  tooltipTemplate: "<%if (label){%><%=label%>: <%}%><%= value/100000000000000000 %>",
});
```

---

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/2g794kxh/

---

Note that there will be a rounding off of the values in the chart beyond a limit. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/30373552/360067 for more information.

If you want to avoid that your best bet would be to treat the static part of your scale / value as a string i.e. your data would be 88, 133, 177, etc. and your scale / value prefix would be 0.150000.....

Answer (score 2):

This has likely changed since the question was asked, but this now appears to be the preferred method:

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'line',
data: data,
options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                // Include a dollar sign in the ticks
                callback: function(value, index, values) {
                    return '$' + value;
                }
            }
        }]
    }
}
});
```

http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html#creating-custom-tick-formats

Answer (score -3):

Try changing the `scaleStepWidth` value in the chart config to something as small as the difference between your values. That should also influence the number of decimal places shown on the scale, as seen in the Chart.Core.js file in Chart.js source on github.

```
new Chart(ctx).Bar(datasets, {scaleStepWidth : 0.00000000000000050});
```

Comment: I'm having the same results even after putting scaleStepWidth : 0.00000000000000050