# How to use chart.js to plot line chart with x axis as time stamp in seconds

Tags: html, websocket, timestamp, chart.js

I want to use chart.js to plot a real time plot of data being received on the html webapp using websockets with the value received as Y-Axis and reception time (in secs) as X-Axis.

Comment: You should show us some actual code, so that we can help you solve your problem, instead of solving it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I assume you know HTML/JavaScript/CSS, websockets,  etc to use chart.js in your apps.

Here is a related post that might be of help to get you started....
     [Chart.js number Y-AXIS label format for many decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34151550/chart-js-number-y-axis-label-format-for-many-decimal-places)

You just have to get started somewhere, sometime!!!

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `addData` method.

From the documentation at http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage-prototype-methods

> **.addData( valuesArray, label )**
>
> Calling addData(valuesArray, label) on your Chart instance passing an
>   array of values for each dataset, along with a label for those points.
>
> ```
> // The values array passed into addData should be one for each dataset in the chart
> myLineChart.addData([40, 60], "August");
> // This new data will now animate at the end of the chart.
> ```